# Versions support on a Samba share

Tags: macos, smb, versions

I have grown to really value Versions in Lion. However it only works on a locally mounted disk on my Mac.

The majority of my files are stored on Samba shares on Linux servers, for which Versions is not supported.

Is there any workaround such that I can use Versions when editing documents on these Samba shares?

Comment: i could see versions being a gateway drug leading to lion server... If you could list why the majority of your files are hosted on linux servers we might have more ability to suggest workarounds.

Comment: My files are on Linux servers because that's the OS the servers run and have done so for many years. As an update, I have tried accessing a Numbers file on a remote Mac running Lion (client) over AFP, and while versions is available locally on that machine it is still not available to the client - same message as seen on a Samba share.

Answer (score 1):

The design of versions is very client Mac centric.

The local Lion OS detects an app is calling document based API and enabled the versioned store in a space that is local to the Mac and different than the actual document.

All version data is stored at `/.DocumentRevisions-V100` and you can explore and test with simple documents in TextEdit to poke at the implementation artifacts.

I suppose you [could mount that directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/how-can-i-share-all-document-revisions-with-another-mac) to the server and experiment, but I don't see any locking or merge functionality and expect a world of hurt if two clients tried to share the same document and version chain simultaneously.

Perhaps the engineering work will be done in the future to allow versions over Xsan storage, but it looks to me that the implementation is only for local versions.